# How to get translation from google translate without application interruption?

Tags: qt, qnetworkreply

Here is a function that get the translation from google translate and return the result:

```
QString QGoogleTranslate::translate(const QString &keyword, const QString &from, const QString &to)
{
    //Locate the translation in the map
    QMap<QString, QPair<QString, QString> >::iterator itr = translations.find(keyword);
    if(itr != translations.end())
    {
        if(itr.value().first == to) {
            result = itr.value().second;
            return result;
        }
    }

    //Translate URL
    QString url = QString("http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=%0&hl=%1&sl=%2&tl=%1&multires=1&prev=enter&oc=2&ssel=0&tsel=0&uptl=%1&sc=1").arg(keyword).arg(to).arg(from);

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);

    //Get reply from Google
    do
    {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);
    } while (!reply->isFinished());

    //Convert to string
    result = reply->readAll();
    reply->close();

    //Free memory
    delete reply;

    //Remove [[[" from the beginning
    result = result.replace("[[[\"", "");

    //Extract final translated string
    result = result.mid(0, result.indexOf(",\"") - 1);

    //Add the translation to the map so we don't need to make another web request for a translation
    translations[keyword] = QPair<QString, QString>(to, result);

    return result;
}
```

But as you see there's a `do while loop` that stops application until `reply->isFinished()`, and when I use `SIGNAL(finished())` from `QNetworkReply` instead of `do while loop`, that's not gonna work!

How can I do that without any interruption?

Comment: "that's not gonna work!" - what do you do? What does not work?

Comment: connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(someSlot())); I don't know why this connection doesn't work.

Comment: You do not get your slot called? Or you cannot establish the connection? Check, what the `connect` function returns.

Answer (score 0):

Move everything after the while to a slot and connect it to `reply`'s `finished()` signal, you'll need to store reply as a field.

You are going to need a new signal that emits the result.

At some point you either need a processEvents loop or return to all the way back to the thread's event loop.

Comment: If I use `moveToThread()`, move this object to another thread and then call this function, would blocking problem solve?

Comment: @Amireas `moveToThread` call will not force method to be executed in separate thread. Slot will be executed in separated thread only if it will be called by connected signal, or with `QTimer::singleShot`, or with `QMetaMethod::invoke`

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you! I needed to move my object to another thread, and I used `QMetaObject::invoke` and it worked. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "blocking" way, you may use `QEventLoop`:

Instead of infinite loop in your code with `processEvents` use following pattern:

```
QEventLoop loop;
connect( reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit );
loop.exec();
```

For working with responce you may use `QJsonObject` and other.

Comment: No, I just want a non blocking way to get the translation.

Comment: This is non-blocking way. But it makes possible to implement asyncronous logic in single flow, without extra slots / connections. It is correct "Qt way".